# Скролл браузера вместе с меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Господа сделал адаптивное меню, которое выезжает по клику на гамбургер. Проблема заключается в том, что на мобилках меню вниз уезжает, а скролл браузера остается на месте. Как сделать, что бы при открытии меню браузер также скролился вниз ? Попытался дать нижнему пункту меню якорь, и сделать плавный скоролл по клику на гамбургер, но не получилось. Выручайте )

Сам сайт https://breeze8.github.io/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(".main-list").slideToggle();
  });

  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    var elementClick = $(this).attr("href")
    var destination = $('#moon').offset().top;
    jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
      scrollTop: destination
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <a href="#" class="hamburger hamburger--vortex" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
  </a>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-list">
      <li id="submenu-toggle"><a href="#" class="main-list__link">Программы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="main-list__link">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="main-list__link">Оборудование</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="main-list__link">Поддержка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="main-list__link">Готовые решения</a></li>
      <li><a href="#moon" class="main-list__link">Автоматизация</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<section class="sec"></section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как мы должны воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: https://breeze8.github.io/ загрузил на гит пейдж

Comment: Судя по примеру, все работает как и должно

Comment: Если есть возможность, откройте на мобилке, сразу увидите, что работает очень плохо :))

Comment: Мне бы хотелось сделать, чтобы браузер прокручивал страничку плавно вниз вместе с меню. А сейчас он резко кидает наверх по клику на гамбургер. Вообще не понятно почему.